# How to center div in the main section, when there is a sidebar?

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar with some buttons and and a maincontent section. What I would like to do is to have the loading spinner when the page is still loading while the data arrives. But I am not able to put the spinner in the center of the page. For now, I have just kept pushing "manually" the div, using margin-left: quantity px.
Any suggestions?

```
 <div class = "wrapper">
   <div class = "sidebar">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
  </div>
  <div id ="maincontent" class ="main_content">
    <app-dashboard></app-dashboard>
  </div>

  <div id = "spinner" class ="main_content" style="margin-top: 300px; margin-left: 750px; display: none">
  
      <div >
        <div class="spinner-border" role="status">
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
  }
  
 
  
  .wrapper .main_content{
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  
.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a Fiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this something you're looking for?

Try with having this on the parent

```
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
```

example - https://jsfiddle.net/kaviharjani/rhy7sce1/1/